# File not opening second time in c++

Tags: c++11, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to open a file using this code which will be called multiple time. First time the file is opening but when this is called for the second time, I am getting some error on the fp1.open.... line, which is:

```
Error in `/home/prosun/Desktop/workspace/fight/Default/fight': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000675310
```

The code:

```
void Writedata::write_file(){

    ofstream fp1;
    int i;

    fp1.open ("output/data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         cout.width(10); fp1 << i << endl;
    }
    fp1.close();
}
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: The code you have cannot compile, the parentheses are unbalanced. Please fix that. – You are not relying on RAII. Just have `ofstream fp1("output/data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);` and no call to `.open` and no call to `.close`. Then this `cout.width()` call does not change anything for the file, you probably want do stream the `width` into `fp1` using `<<`. Then the declaration of `i` outside the loop is not needed, it gets shadowed with the `i` inside of the loop.

Comment: Parentheses is fixed. That is just a mistake. I am talking about the file opening. File opened first time upon calling from another function and the i values are printed. But when it is called for the second time then it showing the above error. The problem is in fp1.open(....) line. That is strange.

Comment: Is the errror "corrupted double-linked list" happening inside this function? I suspect you haven't posted enough code to reproduce your error. Are you just calling this code multiple times?

Comment: I am calling this function multiple times. First time file is opening and writing the information. When this function is called second time then at this line -> fp1.open ("output/data.txt", ios::out | ios::app) the error is showing.